# function to return different query based on parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I've got various kinds of same queries all over my project which is a hell to maintain. So i was thinking to re-organize them all in one place. I'm new to database programming so please excuse me if my thinking is totally wrong and absurd :D

I've tried something like this:

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION GetResults
(
    @Parameter1 int
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH
        Query1 AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.a WHERE ConditionsX),
        Query2 AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.a WHERE ConditionsY),
        Query3 AS (SELECT * FROM dbo.a WHERE ConditionsZ)
    SELECT CASE
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 1 THEN (SELECT * FROM Query1)
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 2 THEN (SELECT * FROM Query2)
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 3 THEN (SELECT * FROM Query3)
    END
)
GO
```

Sadly I get an execution error when running which is not really clear to me:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: The error is, in fact, telling you the issue here; a `CASE` returns a **scalar** value, and your `SELECT *` most certainly won't do that. This smells like an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info) if I am honest.

Comment: CASE in SQL Server returns a scalar value. It is not a control flow statement.

Comment: Please use a stored procedure

Comment: Other : SELECT COl1, Col2, Col3, NULL, NULL FROM ttt WHERE @p = 1 UNION

Comment: SELECT COl1, Col2, Col3, NULL, NULL FROM ttt WHERE @p = 1 UNION [ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, Col3, CCol3, Col4 FROM ccc WHERE @p = 2

Comment: Suggested reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

A mentioned in the comments, `CASE` returns a scalar value so it *can't* return the result of a `SELECT * FROM...` like you have because that will (likely) return multiple columns *and* rows; that very much isn't a scalar value.

More likely what you should be doing is `UNION (ALL)`ing your datasets and have a `WHERE` in them so only return the one you are interested in:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.GetResults (@Paramater1 int)
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN
    SELECT <Explicit Column List, do not use *>
    FROM dbo.a
    WHERE ConditionsX
      AND @Parameter1 = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT <Explicit Column List, do not use *>
    FROM dbo.a
    WHERE ConditionsY
      AND @Parameter1 = 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT <Explicit Column List, do not use *>
    FROM dbo.a
    WHERE ConditionsZ
      AND @Parameter1 = 3;
GO
```

Though this does still smell of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/), if I am honest. I suspect that the problem you are trying to solve, and the problem you've shown us aren't one and the same. Though you will need to ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for ask about that.

Comment: Not sure about the XY Problem. As mentioned, all I want to achieve are reusable queries so I don't have to change them in multiple locations with the risk of forgetting the change somewhere.

It's not about the error message, I just wanted to show what I've tried to make it even more clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: *"all I want to achieve are reusable queries"* That is rarely performant in SQL. T-SQL isn't a programming language, and such actions are often *detrimental* to performance; having functions for logic (which further nest functions) is a nightmare for the data engine to deal with. Repeating the logic in the places you need is, in fact, very likely what you should be doing. So yes, it does seem that this is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)